# Segmentation fault in rails / activesupport 3.1 and ruby 1.9.2

Tags: segmentation-fault, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activesupport, ruby-1.9.2

I upgraded a rails application to rails 3.1 (rc4) and now get random segmentation faults in activesupport. These faults happen when starting the application (rails s) or running tests (e.g. rake spec). The weird thing is that:

- Sometimes all goes well and the segmentation fault does not happen
- When the fault happens, it is always in activesupport, but not always in the same part 
  of it. See below for three different outputs:
- /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc /lib/active_support/core_ext/**class/attribute.rb:66**: [BUG] Segmentation fault
  -/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/**module/remove_method.rb:3**: [BUG] Segmentation fault
- /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/**module/introspection.rb:79**: [BUG] Segmentation fault

I'm not sure what the source of this problem is. Does anybody have an idea? Below is the full log for the first of the three shown above:

```
$ rails s
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:88: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

-- control frame ----------
c:0043 p:0076 s:0123 b:0123 l:000104 d:000122 EVAL   /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:88
c:0042 p:---- s:0121 b:0121 l:000120 d:000120 FINISH
c:0041 p:---- s:0119 b:0119 l:000118 d:000118 CFUNC  :class_eval
c:0040 p:0129 s:0113 b:0113 l:000104 d:000112 BLOCK  /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:66
c:0039 p:---- s:0110 b:0110 l:000109 d:000109 FINISH
c:0038 p:---- s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 CFUNC  :each
c:0037 p:0055 s:0105 b:0105 l:000104 d:000104 METHOD /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:65
c:0036 p:0011 s:0100 b:0100 l:000e98 d:000099 BLOCK  /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/layouts.rb:168
c:0035 p:---- s:0098 b:0098 l:000097 d:000097 FINISH
c:0034 p:---- s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 CFUNC  :class_eval
c:0033 p:0169 s:0093 b:0093 l:000092 d:000092 METHOD /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/concern.rb:122
c:0032 p:---- s:0089 b:0089 l:000088 d:000088 FINISH
c:0031 p:---- s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 CFUNC  :include
c:0030 p:0012 s:0083 b:0083 l:000074 d:000082 BLOCK  /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:226
c:0029 p:---- s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 FINISH
c:0028 p:---- s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 CFUNC  :each
c:0027 p:0276 s:0075 b:0075 l:000074 d:000074 CLASS  /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:225
c:0026 p:0017 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 CLASS  /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:169
c:0025 p:0021 s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 TOP    /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:3
c:0024 p:---- s:0069 b:0069 l:000068 d:000068 FINISH
c:0023 p:0266 s:0067 b:0067 l:000066 d:000066 TOP    /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/meta_search-1.1.0.pre/lib/meta_search.rb:59
c:0022 p:---- s:0065 b:0065 l:000064 d:000064 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0063 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 CFUNC  :require
c:0020 p:0026 s:0059 b:0059 l:000040 d:000058 BLOCK  /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68
c:0019 p:---- s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 FINISH
c:0018 p:---- s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 CFUNC  :each
c:0017 p:0091 s:0051 b:0051 l:000040 d:000050 BLOCK  /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
c:0016 p:---- s:0046 b:0046 l:000045 d:000045 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0044 b:0044 l:000043 d:000043 CFUNC  :each
c:0014 p:0046 s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 METHOD /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
c:0013 p:0021 s:0037 b:0037 l:000036 d:000036 METHOD /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120
c:0012 p:0079 s:0033 b:0033 l:000032 d:000032 TOP    /home/corne/X/projecten/ProjectX/config/application.rb:7
c:0011 p:---- s:0031 b:0031 l:000030 d:000030 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0029 b:0029 l:000028 d:000028 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0016 s:0025 b:0025 l:000016 d:000024 BLOCK  /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:52
c:0008 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 CFUNC  :tap
c:0006 p:0721 s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 TOP    /home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:001598 d:001a18 EVAL   script/rails:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:001598 d:001598 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/rails:6:in `'
script/rails:6:in `require'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in '
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
/home/corne/X/projecten/ProjectX/config/application.rb:7:in `'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/meta_search-1.1.0.pre/lib/meta_search.rb:59:in `'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:3:in `'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:169:in `'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:225:in `'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:225:in `each'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:226:in `block in '
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:226:in `include'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/concern.rb:122:in `append_features'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/concern.rb:122:in `class_eval'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/layouts.rb:168:in `block in '
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:65:in `class_attribute'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:65:in `each'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:66:in `block in class_attribute'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:66:in `class_eval'
/home/corne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb:88:in `block in class_attribute'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_bugreport+0x5f) [0x7f09c4c8fcaf]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x5ff7e) [0x7f09c4b6ef7e]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_bug+0xa2) [0x7f09c4b6fea2]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1140f5) [0x7f09c4c230f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfc60) [0x7f09c4900c60]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(st_clear+0x43) [0x7f09c4c2ac83]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(st_free_table+0x9) [0x7f09c4c2acd9]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x7be87) [0x7f09c4b8ae87]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x7c6c8) [0x7f09c4b8b6c8]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17d0ad) [0x7f09c4c8c0ad]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_add_method+0x34) [0x7f09c4c8c844]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17db5a) [0x7f09c4c8cb5a]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17dc8c) [0x7f09c4c8cc8c]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x176d47) [0x7f09c4c85d47]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17b330) [0x7f09c4c8a330]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x47) [0x7f09c4c8a977]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_ary_each+0x46) [0x7f09c4b3e4f6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17b1a5) [0x7f09c4c8a1a5]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17b23e) [0x7f09c4c8a23e]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x177c44) [0x7f09c4c86c44]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_funcall+0xc6) [0x7f09c4c878c6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x660a2) [0x7f09c4b750a2]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x47) [0x7f09c4c8a977]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_ary_each+0x46) [0x7f09c4b3e4f6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x1f0) [0x7f09c4c8ae90]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x69b26) [0x7f09c4b78b26]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_require_safe+0x6df) [0x7f09c4b7a08f]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_autoload_load+0xa5) [0x7f09c4c645a5]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x155621) [0x7f09c4c64621]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16de4d) [0x7f09c4c7ce4d]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16fc2c) [0x7f09c4c7ec2c]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x1f0) [0x7f09c4c8ae90]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x69b26) [0x7f09c4b78b26]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_require_safe+0x6df) [0x7f09c4b7a08f]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x47) [0x7f09c4c8a977]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_ary_each+0x46) [0x7f09c4b3e4f6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x47) [0x7f09c4c8a977]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_ary_each+0x46) [0x7f09c4b3e4f6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x1f0) [0x7f09c4c8ae90]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x69b26) [0x7f09c4b78b26]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_require_safe+0x6df) [0x7f09c4b7a08f]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x47) [0x7f09c4c8a977]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_obj_tap+0x9) [0x7f09c4bbeb79]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x1f0) [0x7f09c4c8ae90]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x69b26) [0x7f09c4b78b26]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_require_safe+0x6df) [0x7f09c4b7a08f]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17aaa6) [0x7f09c4c89aa6]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1705ae) [0x7f09c4c7f5ae]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1769a3) [0x7f09c4c859a3]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval_main+0xb1) [0x7f09c4c8af91]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x663da) [0x7f09c4b753da]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_exec_node+0x1d) [0x7f09c4b7633d]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_run_node+0x1e) [0x7f09c4b7854e]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby(main+0x4b) [0x40095b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xff) [0x7f09c3cb1eff]
/home/corne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby() [0x400849]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the combination of devise (1.3.4) and [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) (1.1.0.pre) results in these segmentation faults. Disabling one of them "solves" the problem. The root cause is either in one of these gems or in ruby itself. See [this ruby issue](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4821).